# nodeos . Corrupted database after server shutdown. Can't launch

Tags: nodeos

it seems like the PC's shutdown jacked up my blockchain database.

At first it asked something like `replay is required`

I ran it with `--replay-blockchain` - didn't work.

Then I ran it with `--hard-replay-blockchain` - didn't work either.

Here's what I'm getting now when launching nodeos:

[image]

nodeos version - `4115491766`

Plugins enabled :

```
plugin = eosio::producer_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::http_plugin
plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin
```

How to recover from this state and keep the data ?  Thanks for the help.